# Smarty match text like SQL LIKE statement

Tags: smarty

I'm wondering is there a way in smarty to do something like MySQL `LIKE`.
I've got:

```
$value = 'text1/text2';//possible values (text1/text2,text1,text2)
```

And want to do something if in that `$value` there's a `text1`.

Comment: Why not to store the values on an array and call in_array on your template? `{if in_array('text1', $values)}`

Comment: It is stored in DB that way, probably i would nead to explode it to make it into an array. Is there an explode in smarty?

Comment: So you have to register a function that you can call from the template and return the result from there, then you can use the in array function  on the template

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to [help from Raulucco](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32135522), I've written the following code:

```
{assign var=done value="/"|explode:$value}
{if in_array($serch, $done)}
```

This worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Your solution is simpler so better. I was going a more complicated way :-)
Some where on your php files:

```
<?php
$smarty->register_function('get_texts_match', 'text_exists_on_db');

function text_exists_on_db($text) {
  $conn = new PDO($dsn,$user,$pass);
  $q = $conn->prepare("Select text from texts where text like concat('%', ?, '%')");
  $q->execute(array($text));
  return $q->fetchAll(\PDO::FETCH_NUM);
}
```

And the template:

```
{if (in_array('text1', text_exists text="text1"))}
```